# Issue Links meaning in JIRA

Tags: jira

After checking the Atlassian documentation about the kind of links of JIRA's issues (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Linking+Issues)

I couldn't figure out the difference between: "depends on" and "precedes". Does anybody know the difference among them?

Comment: Did you actually find a list of the intended meaning of each link type somewhere? I couldn't, and then eventually figured out that it's because they don't actually do anything, and therefore mean whatever you want them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think someone defined "precedes" locally in your JIRA instance. JIRA admins can define new link types, e.g. "Tests" with text for the incoming and outgoing links.

To answer your question, it's likely a different issue link type. How it is used depends on your local JIRA practices